# Simplest way to set up a 3D OpenGL perspective projection

Tags: c, opengl

There have been many tutorials where each suggests using `gluPerspective` or `glFrustum` with a combination of other things, yet I've had difficulties setting up the right matrix. What code do I need to set up a 45˚ perspective view looking down the +z axis?

So far I have:

```
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClearDepth(1);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glViewport(0,0,width,height);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45,1,0.1,100);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

But that doesn't seem to work. All I get is a black screen when I attempt to draw things.

EDIT: Here's the minimal drawing code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3ub(255,255,255);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
 glVertex3f(20,20,20);
 glVertex3f(20,30,20);
 glVertex3f(30,20,20);
 glVertex3f(30,30,20);
glEnd();
```

Comment: What "things" are you attempting to draw? Where are you trying to draw them?

Comment: Things such as points on (1,1,1) and (2,50,23). They do not appear.

Comment: Are you drawing triangles or points?

Comment: Triangles, but points don't appear either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: Here's the minimal drawing code:
>
> ```
> glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
> glColor3ub(255,255,255);
> glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
>  glVertex3f(20,20,20);
>  glVertex3f(20,30,20);
>  glVertex3f(30,20,20);
>  glVertex3f(30,30,20);
> glEnd();
> ```

Your vertex coordinates lie way outside the viewing volume. First, OpenGL by default "looks" down the negative Z axis, so your Z coordinates must be -100 < z < -0.1 for your choosen near and far clip plane.

But even if you flipped the sign on the Z coordinate, your vertices still would lie outside the 45° FOV. (20, 0, 20) is 45° from the viewing axis, and (30, 0, 20) even farther. Try centering your vertex coodinates around (0,0,-5) like (+/-1, +/-1, -5)

Answer (score 3):

> Things such as points on (1,1,1) and (2,50,23). They do not appear.

Well there's your problem. The default OpenGL camera has the +Z axis pointing *towards* the camera. And since the camera is at Z=0, any position who's Z position is >0 is behind the camera.

Move your points in front of the camera. They need to at least have a -Z position.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see anything.

Comment: Where is your buffer swapping function call?

Comment: Well I'm using SFML and I call `window.Draw()` which is supposed to handle the buffer swapping.

Comment: OK, this thing that's happening now? Where I ask you question after question and you *slowly* post more and more code in response? That's not happening anymore. So if you want additional help, post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Otherwise I can't help; I'm not spending all day prying the specifics of exactly what you're doing out of you.

Comment: Sorry, but the issue wasn't in the OpenGL calls that I didn't include, it was that I was drawing the points too far off. Thanks, though.